# Current Location using FRAGMENT

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, location, currentlocation

Im Facing a issue with getting Current Location Using android java .

when i Run my App in my personal phone i just see a normal map without any Current Location.
and i can't get the permissions.
But when i Run the App in Emulator i see just Toast with Longitude and Latitude.

If any One can Help Please do it.

**Fragment Code**

```
package com.example.Locati;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.Objects;

public class HospitalFragmentMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private double lat, lng;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hospital_map, container, false);


        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity()
                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        }



        return v;

    }



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getCurrentLocation(){
        //to get Current Location

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(50000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "location ruslt is ="+ locationResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (locationResult == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "location is null =", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location:locationResult.getLocations()){
                    if (location != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Curent Location is"+ location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.myLooper());
        Task<Location> task=client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null){
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lng = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Position"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE &&(grantResults.length) > 0 && grantResults[0] + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        getCurrentLocation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before calling getCurrentLocation method check permission on the  onMapReady fuction... Otherwise looks good

Comment: i think problem in your location permission request code block. replace getActivity() instead of requireActivity().

Comment: @GobuCSG I tried it but is still same problem i can get the popup of permission ,if u have any another solution please help me

Comment: @isuruudayanga I already did but still not working

Comment: @isuruudayanga my bad, i haven't look properly. replace your getCurrentLocation to else part move the request permission to the if condition